# Iconv: EILSEQ with ASCII//IGNORE but not with ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE

Tags: iconv

Using iconv with `//TRANSLIT//IGNORE` to convert from utf8 to ascii works fine; it replaces the non-convertible characters to a proper transliteration according to the current locale (de_DE in my case):

```
> echo 'möp' | iconv -f 'UTF8' -t 'ASCII//TRANSLIT//IGNORE'
moep
```

However, when just using `//IGNORE` without `//TRANSLIT`, it throws an error:

```
> echo 'möp' | iconv -f 'UTF8' -t 'ASCII//IGNORE'
mp
iconv: illegal input sequence at position 5
```

I wonder why that happens. The input sequence is exactly the same and shouldn't `//IGNORE` simply skip invalid characters?
When using the iconv C api, I get an EILSEQ error - so basically I don't know if the input string contained invalid UTF8 or not...

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for iconv(1) on linux says the following:

> ```
>   -t to-encoding, --to-code=to-encoding
>          Use to-encoding for output characters.
>
>          If the string //IGNORE is appended to to-encoding, characters
>          that cannot  be  converted  are discarded and an error is printed 
>          after conversion.
> ```

It does skip the character, but also raises the error at the end.

It seems that by using //IGNORE you really cannot distinguish between cases with invalid characters in the input and non-convertible characters. In other words the EILSEQ and EINVAL situations are handled the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to distinguish between presence of illegal sequence in input text and some characters being dropped by examining reported offset of the illegal byte in the input sequence:

- when input indeed contains illegal sequence offset value will be in `1 … (input_bytes_count)` range
- when input was fine but some characters were dropped illegal sequence offset value will be equal to `input_bytes_count + 1`

`möp` size is 4 bytes so reported illegal sequence offset of 5 indicates that input was ok, but some symbols were dropped because they couldn't be represented in the target encoding.